# Jetty run from IntelliJ won't read the jetty-env.xml

Tags: intellij-idea, jetty, jndi

I'm debugging in IntelliJ and since I can't seem to get JBoss to run (due to context and virtual-host name issues), I'm using Jetty 6.1.26.  I was able to run and debug while using a DB connection string that did not involve a jndi.

Now, I need to use a Jndi and can't seem to get Jetty to find it.  I've created a jetty-env.xml file in the WEB-INF directory as such:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!DOCTYPE Configure PUBLIC "-//Mort Bay Consulting//DTD Configure//EN" "http://jetty.mortbay.org/configure.dtd">

<Configure id="wac" class="org.mortbay.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext">
    <New id="jdbc.datasource" class="org.eclipse.jetty.plus.jndi.Resource">
        <Arg><Ref id="wac"/></Arg>
        <Arg>jdbc/datasourceArg>
        <Arg>
            <New class="oracle.jdbc.pool.OracleDataSource">
                <Set name="URL">jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost:1521:xe</Set>
                <Set name="User">user</Set>
                <Set name="Password">password</Set>
            </New>
        </Arg>
    </New>
</Configure>
```

web.inf has this referenced:

```
<resource-ref>
    <description>ConnectionPool DataSource Reference</description>
    <res-ref-name>jdbc.datasource</res-ref-name>
    <res-type>javax.sql.DataSource</res-type>
    <res-auth>Container</res-auth>
</resource-ref>
```

as such

and then the application context creates a bean with it:

```
<jee:jndi-lookup id="jndiDataSource" jndi-name="jdbc.datasource"/>
```

When I run jetty, it tells me that it can't find the data source, so it can't create the bean and the application fails to start.

I suspect that the problem is that jetty is not actually reading the xml file.  I put garbage in there just to see and sure enough there were no errors at all when starting up.

I added plus to my jetty xml

```
<Call name="addLifeCycle">
  <Arg>
    <New class="org.mortbay.jetty.deployer.WebAppDeployer">
      <Set name="contexts"><Ref id="Contexts"/></Set>
      <Set name="webAppDir"><SystemProperty name="jetty.home" default="."/>/webapps</Set>
      <Set name="parentLoaderPriority">false</Set>
      <Set name="extract">true</Set>
      <Set name="allowDuplicates">false</Set>
      <Set name="defaultsDescriptor"><SystemProperty name="jetty.home" default="."/>/etc/webdefault.xml</Set>
      <Set name="configurationClasses"><Ref id="plusConfig"/></Set>
    </New>
</Arg>
</Call>
```

and I referenced the plus xml from the jetty server setup in IntelliJ.

I am at my wits end.  Everything online tells me that jetty automatically scans that directory for this file but it clearly doesn't seem to happen for me.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem doesn't look like caused by Intellij IDEA.
I would suggest you to try to run Jetty with your artifact and startup
configuration without IDEA and compare results.
If there's some difference, please [submit a bug report](http://youtrack.jetbrains.net/).

I'm not familiar with data sources configuration, but able to point to some
possible issues with your configuration:

1. in the file `jetty-env.xml` under the xpath `/Configure/New/@class` should
   be `"org.mortbay.jetty.plus.naming.Resource"`
   instead of `"org.eclipse.jetty.plus.jndi.Resource"`, since the root package
   of Jetty **6.1.26** is `"org.mortbay.jetty"`
   and it was changed to `"org.eclipse.jetty"` with a later version of the
   server.
   Please note, last part of the package also differs (`"naming"`, not `"jndi"`)
2. in the file `jetty-env.xml` under the xpath `/Configure/New/@id` should be
   `"datasource"` instead of `"jdbc.datasource"` (id without prefix)
3. in the file `jetty-env.xml` the first `<Arg>` (containing `<Ref id="wac"/>`)
   looks like not necessary
4. in the file `jetty-env.xml` the second `<Arg>` isn't correctly closed (looks
   like a typo)
5. in the file `web.xml` (not `web.inf`)  `<res-ref-name>` should contain
   `"jdbc/datasource"` instead of `"jdbc.datasource"`,
   as well as in the `<jee:jndi-lookup>` the `jndi-name` attribute should be
   `"jdbc/datasource"` instead of `"jdbc.datasource"`,
   because `"jdbc/"` (not `"jdbc."`) is the common prefix for data source names in
   Jetty.
6. I would recommend to change the data source id to somewhat more
   customized than just `"datasource"`, say at least to `"myDatasource"`

Points **2**, **3** and **5** are taken from the following articles:

- http://jkollage.blogspot.com/2008/01/jndi-with-jetty-env.html
- http://www.plugtree.com/jetty-datasource-jta/

Comment: I tried changing the things you suggested.  I also realized that I was mixing repositories. Now I'm using the following:

'        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.mortbay.jetty</groupId>
            <artifactId>jetty-plus</artifactId>
            <version>6.1.26RC0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.mortbay.jetty</groupId>
            <artifactId>jetty-naming</artifactId>
            <version>6.1.26RC0</version>
        </dependency>'

Answer (score 0):

More than half a decade later, I had the same issue: a `jetty run-war` run config wasn't picking up the jetty-env.xml I had defined in my build resources.

The fix turned out to be updating the run configuration's command line to include the `compile` lifecycle stage, in full `clean compile jetty:run-war -f pom.xml`.